# Download DOM from Google Group page

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to download the DOM from a google group. However, when I try it with PHP, either with POST or GET method, google gives back a sign-in page, not the google group front-page. I tried to use the curl method with same results.

Any idea on what should I do?

P.S: We are migrating the group, so we need the posts published by users.

```
<?php

function curlGet($url, $header){
   $ch =  curl_init();//start curl
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            //curl Targeted URL
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.8 [en] (Windows NT 5.1; U)');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

   $result =  curl_exec($ch);
   $httpResponse = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$targetURL = 'https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/ybsf';
$header = array('Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,bn-bn;q=0.3','Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5');
$responsePg = curlGet($targetURL, $header);
echo $responsePg;
```

Comment: google is very good at detecting 'bots' like this and stopping them

Comment: I can see that! :) Do you know about any workaround?

Comment: the workaround is to use the API, stop breaching their terms

Comment: There isn't API solution for this, bro.

Comment: thats so sad bro that they dont want you breaching the terms you agreed to when you signed up, positively mean of them, bro

Comment: You need to sign in using the cookie jar (really that's what it's called) then you need to send the cookies on subsequent requests to maintain your session.  As others mentioned this may be a violation of their TOS agreement which no respectable web developer will help you to accomplish.  Personally as a professional PHP programmer it's just not worth it to me.